# How to auto-generate comment using custom shortcut in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying create a custom shortcut in IntelliJ to generate some predefined comments.

For example, if I write `//--` and press enter, it should auto-generate:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

The [Postfix Completetion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html) feature looks like it could be used for this but I didn't figure out how to set it up for this scenario. Can someone help?

If Postfix Completetion is not the answer, can I do it with another feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Live Template (`Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`). For example, a template like the following:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
$END$
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

The `$END$` indicates where the text cursor will be placed when the Live Template text is inserted. At the bottom of the Live Template settings screen you can configure in which languages/contexts the Live Template should be available.

[image: Preferences | Editor | Live Templates]